# Postgres override system function

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to override a Postgres system function with user-defined function?

I have created a user-defined function 'substr' but it works only if I specify the schema name, else it uses the system function 'substr'.

Is there a way to override the system function 'substr' and use my user-defined function 'substr' without having to use schema name?

The reason is I want the same functionality of Oracle substr in PG for the existing code base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, but you have to configure `search_path` so that it explicitly contains `pg_catalog` *after* the schema with your function:

```
SET search_path = myfuncs, pg_catalog;
```

Note that `search_path` can be changed by everyone, so your solution relies on nobody changing the parameter. Also, functions can be defined with a custom `search_path`, which would override your setting.

This could lead to surprises in combination with restoring a `pg_dump`, which forces `search_path` empty. I think that your idea is not very robust, and it would be better to name the schema explicitly.